# How to use Azure Cognitive Search to obtain terms from recent and popular searches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We Use Azure Cognitive Search In our E-commerce Application, users can search by product name, category, and code.

Is there Any Way to get all the search history from Azure Cognitive Search?

Is there a way to acquire Azure Cognitive Search's Most Recent Search Terms for Each User?

Is there a way to retrieve the most popular search keywords used by each user from Azure Cognitive Search?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Kusto Query Language (KQL) + Log Analytics to get a list of recent searches.

Here's a sample:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "AzureCognitiveSearch"
| where OperationName == "Search"
| summarize count() by searchText
| top 10 by count_
```

I guess if you pass the user id as a parameter, you should be able to use it as a filter too.

more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-monitor-queries

Comment: Thanks for the Quick update @thiago ,  I was looking at API from Azure query requests in Azure Cognitive Search, not from the AzureDiagnostics.

Comment: logs from Azure Cognitive Search will be sink to Log Analytics. That's definitely where you'll find your data (searches, terms, etc)

Comment: @Ramakrishna.p unfortunately there's nothing else ready to use besides what I post. I added another query sample which would list top 10 popular searches.